# React Native: TypeError: this.state.schedule.map is not an object

Tags: react-native, picker

Hey I am new to React Native and currently I'm trying to put data in a picker using data from API. I'm confused that it got error say TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating this.state.schedules.map). Is there something wrong with the state or is there any concept that I misunderstood

Here is fetch API

```js
export function getSchedule (token, resultCB) {
    var endpoint = "/api/getList"

    let header = {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + token
    };

    return dispatch => {
        return fetchAPI(endpoint, 'GET', header)
            .then((json) => {          
                dispatch({ type: t.SCHEDULE, schedules: json.datas.description });
                resultCB(json.schedules)
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                dispatch({ type: types.EMPTY_SCHEDULE });       
                resultCB(error)
            })
    }
}
```

this is where i put my picker

```js
export const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  token: state.authReducer.token,
  message: state.authReducer.message,
  schedules: state.authReducer.schedules
});

export const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  actionsAuth: bindActionCreators(authAction, dispatch)
});

class Change extends Component {
    
  constructor(){
        super();
        this.state={
            staffId: "",
            schedule: '',
            type_absen: 1,
            schedules: null
        }

    }
    
componentDidMount(){
    this.props.actionsAuth.getSchedule(this.props.token);
  }
  
  render() {
      return (
  
                  <View style={styles.picker}>
                    <Picker
                    selectedValue={this.state.schedule}
                    style={{backgroundColor:'white'}}
                    onValueChange={(sch) => this.setState({schedule: sch})}>
                    {this.state.schedules.map((l, i) => {
                    return <Picker.Item value={l} label={i} key={i}  /> })} 
                    </Picker>
                  </View>

      );
  }
}
  export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Change);
```

Comment: Is `mapStateToProps` is connect to `Change` component?

Comment: it is connected @ravibagul91

Comment: This question is likely a duplicate but as I’m in a rush, I don’t have time to search for an appropriate one.

Comment: Also, are you new to using Redux? You’re getting schedules from your store which means it will be accessible via props. Yet you’ve defined schedules in your Component state as well. As written, your Component state for schedules will never be updated with what you fetch. If you are, it is generally easier to learn React without Redux first to avoid too many abstraction layers while learning the framework fundamentals.

Comment: @Michael Cheng Yes I'm totally new with this, and how should I update with what i'm fetching and thanks for your answer it get rid of the error

Comment: Quick answer is to map this.props.schedules as you don’t need it in state. Long answer that I don’t have time to flesh out is that if you are new to React, don’t use Redux. If you grasp React well and are new to Redux, you will need to just take it slow and learn from errors like this. Just search a lot when you run into errors as it’s almost certain others have run into the same bugs while learning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn’t a React Native specific error. You initialized `schedules` to `null` so on first render, you try to call `.map` on `null`. That’s what is causing your error.

You `fetch` your data correctly in `componentDidMount` but that lifecycle method will fire after the initial render.

One common way to fix this is to initialize `schedules` to an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

First initialise `schedules: []` in the state with empty array, not with the null.

Fetching data in `componentDidMount()` is correct. `ComponentDidMount()` will be called after the first render of component so you have to update the state in the component from the updated store.

you can check whether props is changing or not in `componentWillReceiveProps (depreciated)` or in the latest alternative of componentWillReceiveProps method that is `getDerivedStateFromProps()`.

Below is the syntax for both

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
   if (this.props.schedules !== nextProps.schedules) {
     this.setState({ schedules: nextProps.schedules });
  }
}

static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState){
  if (nextProps.schedules !== prevState.schedules) {
      return { schedules: nextProps.schedules };
  }
  else return null; // Triggers no change in the state
}
```

Make sure your component should connected to store using connect